# Using DHCP on virtual servers (ESXI)

Tags: linux, dhcp, ip-address

I am setting up a small lab with 5 virtual servers running on VMware ESXi 5.

The servers are:

- Network Services server (CentOS 6.4)
- LAMP server (CentOS 6.4)
- File server (CentOS 6.4)
- Zimbra mail server (CentOS 6.4)
- Windows Server 2012 domain controller, etc.

Everything now is set up for DHCP, however, I will be starting and restarting these machines often (as this is a learning environment).  I have already had some issues where I would have to restart (dhclient) some of my machines to renew their IPs and thus regain their connectivity.

Would configuring static IPs for these machines solve that problem?  Or is there another DHCP solution I am not aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Servers should almost never have DHCP assigned IP addresses. In fact I have an entire datacenter where we don't even have a DHCP server.

Set them to be statically assigned and never have to worry about them again. Just keep track of what you set them all to (a spreadsheet is fine) so that you don't mistakenly set two servers to the same IP.